# Remove OK and Cancel button on properties

Tags: isis

How to remove `OK` and `Cancel` button on `VM Jaxb` to make user more easier to input value and move to next field using just single tab. I want to use `VM Jaxb` as `DTO` to transfer data between user and object. So user will not access to object directly.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an action that lets all the properties be updated in a single go:

```
public VM update(String code, String firstName, String lastName) { ... }
```

UPDATE:

The action can be invoked with an inline prompt by associating it with one of the properties using @MemberOrder or .layout.xml

```
@MemberOrder(named="lastName", sequence="1")
public VM update(String code, String firstName, String lastName) { ... }
```

Comment: yes, it no longer show OK and Cancel Button, but it show dialog box.